# Linux Git repository and TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've browsed the web to find the solution but found many variants none of which solves my problem. I'm just starting to use Git and want to have main repository on Linux server but to work locally on windows. I have created repository in the root of website using `git init`:

```
cd /var/www
git init
```

Then I've successfuly added files to it and committed them. I have the history displayed in logs:

```
commit eac728dc06731788e6f39e5ed2a819aa7f0fae1e
Author: Max <my_email@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jul 21 15:06:56 2013 +0400
```

Now I want to be able to clone this repository to Windows. I want to use TortoiseGit for that purpose. I've read that I need to create .ssh keys on Linux and copy them to Windows. I've generated them using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my_email@example.com"` on Linux and copied to `C:\Documents and Settings\User` on Windows. But the other article says that I have to put them to `gitosis-admin/keydir`- I don't know where that is. So my first question is

1. Do I need to copy keys generated on Linux to Windows? If so, what folder should I place them at?
   Then when I open TortoiseGit it asks for URL to git repository. I'm accessing root folder with the IP like `77.777.7.77`. I tried to specify the IP only as the URL since git repository is created in the root folder but I get the error

   > fatal: repository '77.777.7.77' does not exist

   I've also tried the like this - `77.777.7.77/var/www` but to no avail.
2. What URL should be specified if repository is created in the root folder?

   And I assume that I should also create local repository to commit to. But how do I then get it to remote repository?
3. Do I need to create local repository?

Comment: 1) It doesn't matter where keys are created. They can be created in Linux and copied to Windows. 2) If SSH protocol is used to access git server, then the following URL should be specified: ssh://user@sitename/path/to/repository 3) There is no need to create local repository, when cloned it is created automatically

Answer (score 0):

This qualifies for FAQ. You never create a repository, you clone it.

OK - You need to generate key pair in git bash and copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub from windows to user@linux:.ssh/authorized_keys.

Ideally you could use gitolite.

Comment: So I assume by your "You never create a repository, you clone it" phrase that I don't need to create local repository, I need to clone it and it will be created automatically. Are you also saying that I need to create keys in Windows first and then copy them to Linux? Anything to add about the URL?